# If I react to 2 reactions how to remove first

Tags: discord.js

I need help. I don't know what code to add so I can achieve this. I have reaction bot that has 2 reactions. If I react to first and then to second how can bot remove first reaction. I have tried a lot of things but I can't get it to work

Comment: `message.reactions.cache.first().remove()` can do the job?

Comment: Thank you for reply, i tried it doesn't work. Does anyone else have any idea?

Comment: So provide us the log of `message.reactions.cache.first()` please.

Comment: So I actually find something that works: `reaction.message.reactions.cache.first().users.remove(user.id)`
This works for the second one. If i press first one then second one this works, but what if i press first second then first how can it remove second? If u still want log ill send

Comment: So just add `reaction.message.reactions.cache` log and what just said in the question.

Answer (score 0):

first: `reaction.message.reactions.cache.first().users.remove(user.id)`
last: `reaction.message.reactions.cache.last().users.remove(user.id)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).